# What is the type of this dc motor?

Tags: dc-motor, identification

I know that there is a separate excitation dc motor and a series excitation dc motor, but this schematic contains some series and separate coils.

What type is this motor? And what are the coils used for?

[image: photo of label on motor]
[image]

Comment: "Compound-Wound" DC motor. Incidentally, the *more* fields you give it, the more torque but less speed.

Answer (score 2):

Can you determine whether those are resistors, or field coils?

If they are field coils, a useful search term is "[compound motor](https://www.mawdsleysber.co.uk/types-dc-motors/)".

These incorporate both series winding and parallel field coils : the combination can flatten the torque curve of the motor (which falls off at high speed with just a series field winding).

They were big news in "Cassells New Technical Educator" (1897 edition) because of their perfectly flat curve, but according to "The Admiralty Handbook of Wireless Telegraphy" (1925 edition) they are pretty much obsolete.

It may be that connecting either field coil or both can give a range of speeds.

Comment: Thank you brian. 
The J & K terminals aren’t connected in parallel with the armature!!!! Like they are are separated. On the nameplate of the motor, there is different voltages for the field and armature! 
Does this still compound motor?

Comment: I can't see that part of the nameplate ... a couple more photos may be useful. I would expect the field coils to be connected by external switchgear to allow speed switching.  There are different types of compound motor described here http://www.lmphotonics.com/DCSpeed/compound_dc.htm

Comment: This was useful information so far thanks, I add a photo of the name plate but it is in Italian I think, so I couldn’t recognize everything on it

Answer (score 0):

just a educated guess, but with 2 excitation coils you could easily select between 3 speeds with 2 relays, or have one for raw speed selection and one for more fine grained speed regulation.

I remember a elevator utilizing a DC Motor and 2 speeds - but I can't remember if it was just done with a simple resistor, as it was only used for a few second prior to reaching the next level.

But if you do not want the looses in a resistor for long term operation, a second excitation coil sounds clever.

Series excitation gives you a higher momentum, especially at zero speed, so that's good for starting a motor with high load